# Как изменить название пакета при сборке (Flutter)?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Можно ли как-то изменить название пакета при сборке приложения или сделать разные имена пакетов в режима дебага и при сборке?
Просто у меня стоит на телефоне уже готовое приложение, и на нем же стоит версия для дебага. А сам проект на ноуте находится в двух папках, с разными названиями пакетов. Поэтому при релизе постоянно приходится копировать определенную папку из дебага в релиз. Можно ли уместить это в одну папку?

ЭМУЛЯТОР НЕ ПРЕДЛАГАТЬ

Comment: В нативной разработке сборка идёт через Gradle, и в нём, в его скриптах сборки это можно настроить в одну-две строки (если я правильно понял что вам нужно). Если flutter использует похожий механизм сборки, то и там может быть такая фича. Засим, если у вас Gradle - покажите в вопросе его скрипты сборки - возможно получится что-то подсказать. Ну и структуру проекта покажите - то что у вам приходится копировать вручную файлы для разных типов сборок звучит неоптимально - возможно вы что-то не так делаете.

Comment: `то что у вам приходится копировать вручную файлы для разных типов сборок звучит неоптимально` поддерживаю. Предлагаю автору создать новый (единый) проект и перенести код в него...

Comment: У меня есть приложение. Мне необходимо, чтобы на телефоне стояла дебаг версия и релиз версия. Чтобы такое сделать, мне приходится иметь два проекта. Один из которых дебаг, другой релиз. Когда все правки готовы, я копирую папку lib из дебага в релиз и собираю

Comment: просто  для debug'а в build.gradle прописать applicationIdSuffix '.debug'

Answer (score 0):

### Для Android

**Android App Name:**

Изменяем по пути: `app_name/android/app/build.gradle`:

```
...
defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.example.app_name"
    ...
}
...
```

**Package Name:**

Изменяем по пути: `app_name/android/app/src/(main|debug|profile)/AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example.app_name">
// Ещё в main (имя пакета):
<application
    ...
    android:label="app_name"
    ...
>
```

### Для iOS

Изменяем по пути: `app_name/ios/Runner/Info.plist`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    ...
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>app_name</string>
    ...
</dict>
</plist>
```

### Что делать после:

Выполнить команду: `flutter clean` и проверить работоспособность приложения.

---

### Создание нового приложения со своим названием пакета

Для избежания таких случаев следует создавать новые проекты следующим образом:

```
flutter create --org com.yourdomain appname
```

---

[*Источник*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51534616/how-to-change-package-name-in-flutter)